# Pass a function from a Functional Component to a Class based Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Parent Component is like below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import EntityDefinition from "./EntityDefinition";

export default function EntitySelection(props) {

  const testFun = () => {
    console.log("Function activated");
  };
  return (
    <>
        <div>
                <EntityDefinition                  
                  testFun={testFun}
                />{/**Calling a Class based Component*/}
        </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Class based Component (Child)

```
import React from "react";
import { ComboBox, DropdownOption, Button } from "react-widgets";
import axios from "axios";

export default class EntityDefinition extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>       
        <div>
          {" "}
          <Button onClick={this.testFun}>Close</Button>{" "} {/*/Calling the function passed*/}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

but when i clicked the button the `testFun` function is not being called.
i tried something like `onClick={this.state.testFun}` , `onClick={testFun}`
but nothing is happening.
can someone point what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: As a side note. I can't see any good reason to convert a functional component into a class based one. Usually it goes the other way around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testFun` is a prop. So use `this.props.testFun`

```
onClick={this.props.testFun}
```

Answer (score 2):

`testFun` is a prop, and you are using the ES6 class component, and it receives the props as a props object, so you can try accessing it as below

```
onClick={this.props.testFun}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to props passed to a class based components using this.props from inside the class based components:
[Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

In your case, you should change the onClick listener to this:

```
<Button onClick={this.props.testFun}>
```